# pandas in pycharm with too many columns

Tags: pandas, pycharm

I have some dataframes that have more than 700 columns (read into pandas from a csv file). When I use Pycharm IDE and i starting typing `myDF.`, Pycharm IDE hangs up for a few seconds every time after the `.` is typed, as it looks up all the properties including both functions/modules and columns in `myDF`.

Is it possible - within Pycharm IDE - to selectively disable the lookup of pandas data frames' columns and only lookup functions/modules whenever the `.` is pressed after a data frame, i.e. when I press `.` after `myDF` to make it `myDF.`, the Pycharm IDE should only look up functions/modules and not columns?

Comment: Even if you could do that the columns are accessible as attributes of the df so I don't think you could disable that or want to in the general case

Comment: I want the columns to be accessible as attributes. I just would like to avoid Pycharm from hanging up to lookup all attributes if possible.

Comment: I also have this problem with 200 columns

Answer (score -1):

Press on to active pycharm window <kbd>Shift+Alt+f9</kbd> and click `Edit configurations`. New window appears. On left side of the window you can see `Defaults`. Double click and open tree. Select `Python`.

Now, you will sell default settings right side of the window. Here `Emulate terminal in output console`. You get to check this.

Now you will get all (hidden) columns name.